# calculate proper arp reply timeout c++

Tags: c++, timeout, arp

I have a program that sends arp packets to all hosts in a network to figure out which ones are up, which works fine so far.

I just have some difficulties setting a proper timeout for the reply, so far I got this:

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 10000; //0.01sec
if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv)) < 0) {
    ...
}

 ...

 if ((bytes = sendto(sock_fd, ether_frame, packet_length, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &device, sizeof (device))) <= 0) {
        //error handle
    } else {
        if ((bytes = recv(sock_fd, packet, sizeof(packet), 0)) <= 0) {
             ...
        } else {
        ...
```

When running the program with the above set value of 0.01sec, I sometimes get all replies and sometimes some replies are missing. When I increase the value to e.g. 1sec I get all values. But since there are a lot of requests to send, with 1sec it takes a huge amount of time till it finishes.

Is there a better way to calculate the timeout for the replies? Probably dynamically?

Comment: Can't you send your requests in parallel?

Comment: How with threads or fork?

Comment: You can do it without threads. `sendto` is non-blocking. So, you can schedule all your `send(...)` calls first (each `send(...)` has its own socket). After that do a `recv(...)` on each socket to receive the messages.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your suggestion, the sendto and recv are performed in a while-loop right now. How am I supposed to schedule the the sending with the `send` command and then recv them for each socket?

Comment: I would create an evenloop, using epoll for example, and in the wait add the timeout you desire. If you can use boost, take a look at boost.asio, if you can't, take a look at libuv, or any kind of asinchronous/event oriented library. Your problem looks like an asynchronous I/O problem, so it would be a good idea to start taking a look at that.